# Implementing UserDefaults using properyWrapper causes weird problem

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, property-wrapper

I am trying to implement UserDefaults class using `@propertyWrapper`. What I am trying to do is creating a wrapper class for my app user preferences. So I wrote following code.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Storage<T> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T
    var projectedValue: Storage<T> { return self }
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    init(key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    func observe(change: @escaping (T?, T?) -> Void) -> NSObject {
        return DefaultsObservation(key: key) { old, new in
            change(old as? T, new as? T)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I'd like to observe UserDefaults value changes. So I implemented an observation class named `DefaultsObservation`.

```
class DefaultsObservation: NSObject {
    let key: String
    private var onChange: (Any, Any) -> Void

    init(key: String, onChange: @escaping (Any, Any) -> Void) {
        self.onChange = onChange
        self.key = key
        super.init()
        UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: key, options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard let change = change, object != nil, keyPath == key else { return }
        onChange(change[.oldKey] as Any, change[.newKey] as Any)
    }

    deinit {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: key, context: nil)
    }
}
```

Also my AppData class is following.

```
struct AppData {
    @Storage(key: "layout_key", defaultValue: "list")
    static var layout: String
}
```

However, when I tried to add and listen changes `layout` property it is not working properly.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    AppData.$layout.observe { old, new in
        print(old)
    }
}
```

When I debugged it, `deinit` is working as soon as `viewWillAppear` method invoked. When I commented out `deinit` method for removing observer everything is working perfect. I think closing `deinit` can cause some memory problems. So I do not want to commented it out. What am I missing and how can I solve it?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but there is a type mistake. `string(forKey:` in `UserDefaults` returns always`String` (or `nil`). To be more generic you have to write `object(forKey:`

Comment: Thank you I consider to write more generic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `observe(change: @escaping (T?, T?)` initialise `DefaultsObservation` object and returns the value. There isn't any strong reference to this object so that's why it's deallocated and `deInit` is being called. You need to keep a strong reference of this object. For Example

```
var valueObserver: NSObject? = nil
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    valueObserver = AppData.$layout.observe { old, new in
        print(old)
    }
}
```